# access the onclick handler of a button contained in a templated handlebars page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I'm working on a web application that uses Handlebars. I'm trying to access the onclick event handler of a button from a `scripts.js` file (that contains some utility scripts, functions, etc). I have a `main.handlebars` that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ... stuff ...
    <title>I'm Stupid</title>
</head>
<body >
    ... navbar ...

    <div class="container">
        {{{body}}}         <--- Important!
    </div>

    ... footer ..
</body>
</html>
```

This is another file that is passed into {{{main}}}:

```
... some html ...
<input type="button" id="submit" class ="button_img_only flex-wrap btn-lg" placeholder="amount" value ="Say Hi!"/>
... more html ...
```

I have a directory that contains utility javascript files. In a file called `stripe_scripts.js`, I try to access the onclick event handler of the `submit` button. However, I get a null return value, which I assume means the button was not found?

My questions are these: How do I access the buttons onclick handler? After some Googling, I found a solution that looks like this:

```
<script id="text-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{{main}}}      <-- ??????????????
</script>
```

and then to access the submit button, use this:

```
var source   = document.getElementById('text-template').innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {body: tbody};
var html    = template(context);

document.getElementById('submit').innerHTML = html;
// bind the submit buttons onclick event handler to handle clicks
```

How would I use the above template with my existing project? Do I need to put my entire page's HTML code into the {{{main}}} placeholder, inside a script tag?

Is there a better way to do it using Handlebars? (Based off of this: https://handlebarsjs.com/installation/when-to-use-handlebars.html#when-not-to-use-handlebars, Handlebars should not have been used in the first place). Should I move away from Handlebars and use a single-page architecture with something like Angular or React? Obviously, I'm new to web development, and I could use some help.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. I don't see the word `click` in any of your code examples. What do you want to happen when the button is clicked?

Comment: @76484 When the button is clicked I want it to redirect to the Stripe checkout page... The reason I didn't include it in the question was because it doesn't really matter what the button click does. Assume it displays an `alert` in the browser

Comment: There are things in your example code that don't make sense. The fact that you have a `main.handlebars` tells me that you are rendering your templates server-side. If so, you shouldn't also require client-side templates, like your `id="text-template"` script. It looks to me like there is some confusion about how/where your views get rendered (ie., server vs client). That aside, so long as you have appended your HTML with your button element to the DOM _before_ binding the click handler, there should be no issue. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/8gyza6of/

Comment: Perhaps you need just to include your `stripe_scripts.js` file at the end of the `<body>` in your `main.handlebars` file.